# How to install amap in homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I got the following error. Could anybody let me know how to install it in homebrew? Thanks.

```
$ brew install amap
Error: amap has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the formula is disabled, and the technical details are in [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/65291#issuecomment-750743982).

If you want to try out the pre-built bottle, you can use this hacky solution:

- `brew edit amap`
- comment out or remove that `disable!` line
- save the change
- `brew install amap`
- revert the `disable!` change by `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout HEAD -- Formula/amap.rb`

here is my installation result.

```
$ brew install amp
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/amp-0.6.2.moja
Already downloaded: /Users/rchen/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8186d3a7491dd11a17933819130d1f56d2b39fa521815d9b4d0831be93a79fe5--amp-0.6.2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring amp-0.6.2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/amp/0.6.2: 8 files, 4.3MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the formula on homebrew was recently edited to prevent installs on MacOS Sierra. Time to patch the src or upgrade.  See here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/e3a76a8d38f396d26b82464c3e7c6b54b0b9a112#diff-82c69a605f5b89b1aab28ae16242992798c78688166b168557f9f2066734d343